# How transform a string into a variable name - PHP?

Tags: php, variables

I have a php file ("gion.php") with inside an array:

```
 $gion = array('ok');
```

I want to include this file and print the array.

```
 $name_user = "gion";
 include "profili/".$name_user.".php";
 $file_profile= "$".$name_user;

 print_r($file_profile);
```

`print_r` doesn't work because i suspect `$file_profile` is a string, so i can change it in a name variable ?

```
"$gion" (string) -> $gion (variable)
```

thanks a lot

*EDIT*: i want to print array('ok') and not "gion"

Comment: ```$name_user "gion";``` What does this mean? Or is there a typo?

Comment: Are you looking for variable variables? https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @esQmo_ sorry i lost "="

Comment: @Andreas i tried (tried also eval) but i don't understand how use it... i'm not good programmer and i don't speak english very well (so is difficult to understand)

Comment: No, don't do it this way. You don't need variable variables. Use normally `$file_profile = $name_user` or use directly `$name_user` for finding prodile file.

Comment: Try $file_profile = $$name_user; That should give you an array if I am not mistaken. But your code would be diff to debug and read

Comment: @pavel are you sure ? seems strange.... $name_user is only a string without $

Comment: @Borja sure. You don't need to have variable `$gion`. Not as a beginner programmer (I'm programing 10+ years and I had never needed to have `$gion` variable in my code). What should `$file_profile` do?

Comment: You are mixing up the filename 'gion.php' and the variable in 'gion.php' called $gion. When you include 'gion.php' then $gion becomes a global variable, so you can do _$file_profile = $gion;_ and print it or directly do _print_r($gion);

Comment: @pavel LOL i tried but it print "gion" and not content of array

Comment: @lukas.j sorry but i don't understand.... can you write an answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File: gion.php:

```
$gion = array('ok');
```

File: main.php (or whatever your filename is):

```
$name_user = "gion";
include "profili/" . $name_user . ".php";
$file_profile = ${$name_user};

print_r($file_profile);   // this also works: print_r($gion);
```

This will print:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ok
)
```

Comment: is there only a big difference :D in my code i don't have $file_profile = $gion LOL and i can't write it.

Comment: i have "$".$name_user but not work

Comment: Change it. It is the reason it does not work. Or do you want to make it versatile for different $name_user?

Comment: my friend if the code is written like this there will be a reason right? I have 250 files, each of them is about a user's profile. Each file has a specific array.

In this code I have an array with the list of names and a for loop where I parse each filename and include the user's file.
What I would like to do is print the contents of the array.

We are inside a for loop.
Now you understand why there's "$".$name_user?

Comment: You should have mentioned that in you original post. I made the necessary change.

Comment: It is really important to state such additional facts when you post a question. Glad it work out. By the way: @Andreas guided you in the right direction: _Are you looking for variable variables? php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php_.